# Query SQL Server 2005 database from SQL Server 2008 side

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two databases, one is SQL Server 2005 and the other is SQL Server 2008. Sometimes I need to access data from one database on the other.

E.g. if I am working on my 2005 server I can access the data on the 2008 server by typing the servername before the database

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Server].[Database].[Table]
```

This works fine. However if I try to do it the other way round, I get this message:

> Could not find server '**servername**' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

So I can get data from my 2008 server in my 2005 server, but not the other way round. Can anybody explain to me why, and does anyone have a solution for this?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R8.

Comment: Look up `sp_addlinkedserver`.

Comment: Thanks I just looked it up. Trying to execute the stored procedure gives me this:

*You cannot specify a provider or any properties for product 'SQL Server'.*

Comment: And if I don't specify a provider I get this instead: *You must specify a provider name with this set of properties.*

Comment: Edit you question and add how you are calling `sp_addlinkedserver` and error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved this by adding my linked connection in the sys.servers using below code:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'servername'
```